# Is there any way to vertically-align iText (iTextSharp) text using ColumnText?

Tags: itext

Is there any way to vertically-align text using ColumnText? I am using iTextSharp

```
Chunk c = new Chunk(text, this.detailFont);
Phrase myText = new Phrase(c);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, llx, lly, urx, ury, lineheight, Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
ct.Go();
```

My text appears at the top of the box I specify. I would like it to align with the bottom of the box.

```
 as it is                 as it should be
|---------------|        |---------------|
|   some text   | --->   |               |
|               |        |   some text   |
|---------------|        |---------------|
```

Comment: A `ColumnText` is filled top-down. What you can do, though, is first filling the `ColumnText` in emulation mode,  read the height of the filled area, and then filling the `ColumnText` with a rectangle moved down accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution:

```
Chunk c = new Chunk(text, this.detailFont);
Phrase myText = new Phrase(c);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, llx, lly, urx, ury, lineheight, Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
ct.Go(true);
if (ct.LinesWritten == 1)
{
    ury = ury - (this.rowheight);
}
ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, llx, lly, urx, ury, lineheight, Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
ct.Go();
```

`ct.Go(true)` -- Apparently the "true" here indicates the ColumnText is created in "Simulation" mode. I was not aware of this mode before comments to my question were posted.

`if (ct.LinesWritten == 1)` checks the number of lines that were written. If only one line was written, I shrink the size of the upper-right-y corner of my rectangle.

`ct.SetSimpleColumn(myText, llx, lly, urx, ury, lineheight, Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);` when I call this line the second time, the `ury` (upper-right-hand corner) location has been changed and the box is smaller.

`ct.Go()` - The second time I call this, I don't pass the "true" param so the second call is not simulation mode and writes the data to the document.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of **birwin** is just not working. The *ColumnText* alignment is accept only horizontal alignments. And this is working till *ColumnText* text is in Text mode. When you call the *ColumnText.AddElement* the *ColumnText* switches to CompositMode and the Alignment has no effect.

If you really want to Vertical Alignment in *ColumnText* then you have to create a content which has aligned content and must add to *ColumnText*. Only the *Table* and *Cell* the correct object where vertical alignment has any effect.

So first we have to create a table, with one column and one cell. And set the size of the cell to same as column text size. 
And second, this table must be added to *ColumntText*

Here is my code:

```
        // create doc
        var pdfDoc = new Document( PageSize.A4 );
        var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance( pdfDoc, new FileStream( Path.Combine( Path.GetTempPath(), "test.pdf" ), FileMode.Create ) );

        pdfDoc.Open();

        var canvas = pdfWriter.DirectContent;
        canvas.SaveState();
        canvas.Rectangle( 100, 100, 100, 100 );
        canvas.SetRgbColorFill( 255, 128, 128 );
        canvas.Fill();
        canvas.RestoreState();

        // create font
        BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont( BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false );
        Font times = new Font( bfTimes, (float)10, Font.ITALIC, new BaseColor( (int)232434 ) );

        Phrase myText = new Phrase( new Chunk( "Hello World", times ) );
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText( canvas );

        /* wrong birwin code : 
        ct.SetSimpleColumn( myText, 100, 100, 200, 200, ct.Leading, Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM );
        */

        // new working code: crreate a table
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable( 1 );
        table.SetWidths( new[] { 1 } );
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;
        table.AddCell( new PdfPCell( myText )
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
            VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM,
            FixedHeight = 100
        } );
        ct.SetSimpleColumn( 100, 100, 200, 200 );
        ct.AddElement( table );
        ct.Go();

        pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I would only add `Border = 0` to the PdfPCell initialisation if you don't want a solid border shown around the cell.